# Buzzing noise on headset when moving mouse

Tags: audio, bios, headset, interference

I have a computer with these specifications. 
I use Turtle Beach X12 Headphones. When I move my USB mouse (Logitech G400) I hear a buzzing sound. This is not a software problem as this happens when I am in BIOS Setup.

[image: System Specs]

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you have a wireless mouse that opperates at a frequency your speakers pick up? (just like some speakers make noise just before a mobile phone is about to ring)?

Comment: Like I said in the first post it is USB.

Answer (score 0):

This looks a lot like an issue with onboard sound cards where they would pick up interferences from other components on the motherboard.

This used to be *somewhat common* on cheap integrated audio chipsets, circa mid-2000's.

Work arounds:

- Use optical output if available (my assumption is that it is the DAC of the sound card that picks up noise, so bypassing analog output all together should help).

  - This does not help since you have headphones.
- Buy a cheap USB sound card to see if it helps

  - [Something like this maybe?](http://dx.com/p/165958)